# Haskell Integer not acting as Integer

Tags: haskell, variable-assignment

So I'm defining a variable/function that takes two inputs and displays a series of 1's and 0's

```
bin 0 0 = '0'
bin 0 1 = '1'
bin 0 2 = '1'
bin 0 3 = '0'
bin 0 4 = '1'
```

now I want to create a duplicate of the bin variable except that at 0 3 there should be a 1 so I tried to achieve this in a new function

```
changeBin w z = binNew where 
                binNew w z = '1'
                binNew x y = bin x y
```

yet if I do it like this it gives me a pattern match redundant warning and when I call changeBin 0 3 it gets into a loop but when I change the function to

```
changeBin w z = binNew where 
                binNew 0 3 = '1'
                binNew x y = bin x y
```

this works but I want to do it the first way so I can change it anytime without writing a whole function but I dont know why it gives me a redundant error when I write the same just with the numbers it works

I am new to haskell bear with me thanks

any help is appreciated on what my error is on the first function

Comment: You specified here that `changeBin 0 3` returns a function `binNew`, and that `binNew` asks for two new variables.

Comment: Also, `binNew w z`, `binNew x y` and `binNew hello world` are the same thing definitions.

Comment: Note that `0` and `3` do not appear anywhere in the definition of `changeBin` that doesn't work.

Comment: How do I pass the two integers to binNew without asking for new variables and the 0 and 3 are just example numbers in the next I want to change 0 and 2 and then 0 and 4

Comment: @HaskellPlease: like `changeBin w z = binNew w z where ...`, but it makes the `where` clause rather "useless".

Comment: doing it like that doesnt duplicate the other numbers of `bin` right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1 changeBin w z = binNew where 
2                 binNew w z = '1'
3                 binNew x y = bin x y
```

The `w` on line 1 and the `w` on line 2 are different variables.  `w` on line 2 does not become a pattern that only matches when it has the same value as the `w` given on line one –– instead it defines a new variable that shadows the old one.  You need to explicitly compare:

```
changeBin w z = binNew
    where
    binNew w' z' 
        | w' == w && z' == z = '1'
        | otherwise = bin x y
```